# Django Rest Framework : managing relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following 3 tables

movies 
ID | shortDesc | uploaded

sources 
ID | name | createDate

movieSources
movieID | sourceID

How do I link them all together to get all the data in one REST call 
I have the below code and it doesnt seem to work

models.py

```
class movieSources(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                db_table = "movieSources"
        movieID = models.IntegerField()
        sourceID = models.IntegerField()

class movies(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                db_table = 'movies'
        uploaded = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        sourcesMovie = models.OneToOneField(movieSources)

class sources(models.Model):
        class Meta:
                db_table = 'sources'
        createDate = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Serializers.py

```
class MovieSourcesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = movieSources

        fields = ('movieID', 'sourceID')


class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sourceID = serializers.IntegerField(source='sourcesMovie.sourceID')

    class Meta:
        model = movies

    fields = ('id','uploaded', 'sourceID')
```

Comment: Both models `movies` and `sources` point to the table `movies`. Is it just a typo here in your question or it exists also as such in your original code?

Comment: Sorry typo .. corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to rethink the design of your models. As described in the opening, there is a many-to-many relationship between `movies` and `sources`. `movieSources` would be the intermediate table, which isn't necessary to be declared as a model, as Django's ORM takes care about that.

Also I would suggest you to follow the conventions and write your model class names in PascalCase. Use rather singular names for this purpose.

models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    short_desc = models.CharField('short description', max_length=255)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movies'


class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='sources')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sources'
```

So should the models look like according to your description. The option `auto_now=True` will create automatically the timestamp when an entry is created. The models are connected with a m:n relation. Django takes care for everything else behind the doors.

Now you can create your serializers:

serializers.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sources = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = (short_desc, uploaded, sources)


class SourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Source
        fields = (name, create_date, movies)
```

The `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` will fetch the related data.

I didn't test the code and wrote it as I remember, but I think it should work out of the box. I hope the answer helps you and gives you an idea how to solve your problem better.